# Could not find file android-support-multidex.jar'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i am new to xamarine, i have created a project and while i try to run it i get this error

```
The "CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 
'C:\Users\TeamLead\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\support
\multidex\library\libs\android-support-multidex.jar'.
```

i have chekcked  Enable Multi-Dex in Android Options in Visual Studio 2013
updated all repositories but i am unable to run the project

Answer (score 1):

I tend to get this error sometimes and I usually fix it by doing a Clean + Rebuild out of my own experiences. Should go away after first or second Clean + Rebuild.

Alternatively, you might have to install the Android Support Library from the SDK Manager. You might have to check the "Obsolete" option in the SDK manager to find this. ([source](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/19#issuecomment-243757476))